# How to set ctrl button active (simulate that it is pressed) when page loads in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, keypress, keydown

I have embedded a google map iframe into an html document. I want when the user rotates/scrolls mousewheel up or down over the iframe, it should zoom in and out on the map respectively. But here, a message shows that hold ctrl+scoll to zoom in and out.
[image]

I want to get rid of this message. When the document loads, scrolling over the map iframe should zoom in and out and not display this message.
If setting any iframe property would solve this kindly suggest that also.

I tried searching a lot, but only found one relevant post that says user has to press the key.
This is my script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Map</title>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d106216.73119953761!2d73.06608639999999!3d33.701888!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sen!2s!4v1681887705873!5m2!1sen!2s" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
</body>
 
  </html>
```